# how to create multi-page screen with libgdx scene2d?

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx

I want to create a multi-page level selection screen (just like in angry birds level selection) that user could navigate between pages by dragging (swiping) his/her finger on the screen horizontally.
I checked ui widgets in scene2d so I just found 'ScrollPane' that maybe useful but its functionality differs from what I want.
Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing built into LibGDX for this function. However, it is possible to implement this with input listeners and a ScrollPane. You would have to determine how many 'pages' you want and then build a table where each cell is the size of the pane. Then when a user does a 'flick' you would change the scrollX value to match what the next/previous page is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nEx.Software has a nice little tutorial that explains how to do just this at http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2013/05/09/libgdx-making-a-paged-level-selection-screen/.  His solution involves extending ScrollPane to add paging functionality.

Answer (score 1):

this is more simple:

http://moribitotechx.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/23-tutorial-libgdx-mtx-test7levelscreen.html

good luck